# String Split: Key not found exception

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a string message that is separated by ':Item:' I want to put the items next to ':Item:' in a dictionary using a unique key

```
    string input = "aaaaa:Item:ID1222222:Item:ID3444444:Item:ID4555555";
    var response = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string[] values = input.Split(':');

       for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
       {
         if (!values[i].Contains("Item"))
           {
           // use the id as a unique key 
              response.Add(values[i].Substring(1, 3), values[i]);

          }
           Console.WriteLine(response["ID1"]);
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
```

But this is giving me a key not found exception since values[0] does not have the ID i used as a key.
How can I skip the first element in the collection? or is there another efficient way?

**EDIT:**
What I want to put in the dictionary is :

```
  key = "AA", value = "aaaaa"
  key = "ID1",    value = "ID1222222"
  key = "ID3"      valeu ="ID3444444"
 key = "ID4"      value "ID4555555"
```

thanks

Comment: You want to add `aaaaa` as well in the dictionary?

Comment: what should be the expected output ?

Comment: I updated my post. EDIT: What I want to put in the dictionary is :

  key = "AA", value = "aaaaa"
  key = "ID1",    value = "ID1222222"
  key = "ID3"      valeu ="ID3444444"
 key = "ID4"      value "ID4555555"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` to get your expected output:

```
var dictionary = input.Split(':')
                 .Where(x => !x.Contains("Item"))
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Substring(0, 3), x => x);
```

Results in `LINQPad`:

[image]

Note: `Substring` might throw exception if you have a `key` that contains less than three characters,in order to fix that you can do the following:

```
var dictionary = input.Split(':')
             .Where(x => !x.Contains("Item"))
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Length >=3 ? x.Substring(0, 3) : x, x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "aaaaa:Item:ID1222222:Item:ID3444444:Item:ID4555555";
            var response = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string[] values = input.Split(':');

            for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!values[i].Contains("Item"))
                {
                    // use the id as a unique key 
                    response.Add(values[i].Substring(0, 3), values[i]);

                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < response.Count; i++)
            {
                if (response.ContainsKey("ID1"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(response["ID1"]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```